# How to extract different frequencies from a WAV file in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, frequency, frequency-analysis

I'm trying to play different frequencies at equal time intervals from one computer and analyze them with another.
So far I have managed to play frequencies, record them from the other computer and save them in a WAV file using Python.
My problem starts when I'm trying to analyze the file. I had tried a lot of methods I found online, but none of them have worked.
Can someone please recommend a library or an algorithm that fits this description? :)

This is what I've got:

```
def getFreq(start):
    end = start + 10
    sr, data = wavfile.read("somefile.wav")
    sp = int(sr * start / 1000)
    ep = int(sr * end / 1000)
    l = 10 / 1000
    c = 0
    for i in range(sp, ep):
        if data[i] < 0 and data[i + 1] > 0:
            c += 1
    return int(c / l)
```

Comment: magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data))

Answer (score 0):

Look for implementations of STFTs (short term Fourier transform) or spectrogram visualizers.